# Windows 7 120 GB disc drive C full

Tags: windows

I have windows 7 and my disc drive has a capacity of 120 GB. From one day to another it tells me that my disc C is full in a red bar but I dont have many programs installed. I deleted all of my videos, games, music, pictures, etc and I was able to free up 30 GB. I ran the disk cleaner and emptied the TEMP folder and garbage can but it still shows a 70GB used. Can I get some help from the experts PLEASE!!!

Comment: Have you used any kind of visualation program like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) yet to see what folder is taking up all the space? If it's a windows folder don't just go deleting stuff you don't know what it is. Come back here with screenshots.

Comment: Have you checked if it was being used up by system restore?

Comment: Scott, no I havent used WinDirStat and dont know how to use it. I did go on the files and check the sizes on them and on of them seem to be super big. Thanks

Comment: CPX, I dont know how to check system restore. Actually, I dont really know how to so im lost.

Comment: Techie007, should I follow whats on your link?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I downloaded WinDirStat and now I am running it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it frooze on me right at the end before it could finish.

Comment: How do I paste screen shots on here?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain There is a folder under Windows called Logs and when I open it up it has a folder in it called CBS that shows a size of 26.6 GB. I dont know what that is?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you ran the [System File Checker utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_File_Checker) and [it generated a lot of logs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928228). If you do not need the logs from running `SFC` you can safely delete it.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I delete them?

Comment: Umm, click on the log and press delete???